# How do I open an Excel-workbook in read-only mode without a user-prompt

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I use the VBA code below to open a workbook but I get a user-prompt when the workbook is already-opened by another user asking if I would like to open in read-only mode.
I'd like to open the workbook in read-only mode directly without the read-only user prompt.

```
Sub Report()

    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim Filechosen As Boolean
    Dim Savebutton As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim book As Workbook
    
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "Old Excel Files", "*.xls"
    fd.Filters.Add "New Excel Files", "*.xlsx"
    fd.Filters.Add "macro Excel Files", "*.xlsm"
    fd.Filters.Add "any Excel Files", "*.xl*"
    
    fd.FilterIndex = 4
    
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False
    
    fd.InitialFileName = "https:sharepoint address/BFs/"
        
    Filechosen = fd.Show
    

    If Not Filechosen Then
        MsgBox " No File Selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    fd.Execute
    
    
    
For Each sh In Worksheets: sh.Visible = True
  
Next sh




End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are giving the command to open the file, it has an optional command to open it in readonly

Just mention it as Readonly:=True

It will not prompt the user

Let me know if you need further clarification

Comment: thanks for the advice - I have tried to add it into the code but its rejecting the action with a notification saying compile error expected: expression

Answer (score 1):

You can open the workbook yourself using the VBA workbooks.open method once you get the filename from the dialog.

Replace in your code as needed. You'll get the idea

```
Dim xlFileName As String
Dim wb as Workbook

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1

      If .Show Then
           xlFileName = .SelectedItems(1)                   
      Else
           MsgBox " No File Selected"
           Exit Sub
      End If

End With

    wb.Workbooks.Open (xlFileName), ReadOnly:=True
```

You can then copy the worksheets in that workbook from the wb.worksheets collection.

Comment: am not fully following you on this as I have tried the code and its kicking me out after I am selecting the document and not opening it up